# Openlayers: Rendering stuck - Unable to print PDF with higher resolution

Tags: printing, rendering, openlayers, vector-tiles, angular-openlayers

I am trying to use the openlayers example to print the PDF & it is working for lower resolution prints.

I am trying to fit the map to a certain polygon extent:

```
         `  map.setSize(printSize);

           map

             .getView()

            .fit(feature.getGeometry().getExtent(), {

               size: map.getSize()

               });`
```

Maps zooms in after this call but I am expecting the map to get rendered and pass the below event but it never happens:

map.once("rendercomplete", function () {

I have multiple Vector tile layers

ol/source/VectorTile

ol/layer/VectorTile

My print size is a0.  Is there any optimization I could perform to address this issue ?

Comment: It might be a browser limitation.

1. Implement server-side printing using Node.js and the `canvas` package (which relies on Cairo).
2. Convert the images to SVG paths, which might be more efficient for rendering.
3. Split the image into smaller chunks and then stitch them together when rendering on the canvas.

Comment: Split the rendering into smaller extents, and add each extent to the pdf separately, a 5 x 5 grid of small extents works for A0 300dpi here https://codesandbox.io/s/export-pdf-forked-tfnwrd?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike, thanks it worked for us. can you help on one strange issue, while printing if we move to another window from chrome the rendering becomes stopped and not printing.  is there any possibility to run it in the background even we move to another window?